# How can I get to the chests?

Tags: a-wizards-lizard

In **A Wizard's Lizard**, there's the occasional room per dungeon with a special chest made unavailable by blocking rocks. Here's one from the second stage, but I've seen a golden one early on regularly.

[image: imprisoned chest]

How should I be able to get those chests? Is flying an option in this game? Bombs, maybe?
What are my (maybe item-related) possibilities here?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the first-stage-chest https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqjKj.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chest require you to be in normal form to reach it, your character is in the ghost form. There is also a room on that floor that is empty aside from a resurrection circle, if you stay in that circle until the progress bar fills you revive back to normal form with half of your max hp

The chest on the second floor of the cemetery needs you to be in the ghost form to access it. That chest always contains the key for the chest in your picture.

Comment: And I was seconds away to ask about that strange circle room :D